# How can i clear all validators on another component, angular 7 reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have an application that is essentially one big form.  If a user selects a boolean value on one component, the form group on a sibling component should have all its validation cleared.

How can this be achieved?

This method disables a tab on our application, when the tab is disabled, it should also clear all validation on all form groups on that component:

```
getSkipLogic() {
  this.skipLogicService.getSkipLogic().subscribe(data => {
    (data || []).forEach(item => {

      if (item.toQuestion === 'Q46') {
        const setValue = item.values === 'beforeDate' ? 'Yes' : 'No';
        this.contradictValue.Q46 = setValue;
        this.dependencySectionOne.get('BornBeforeJanuary1996').
          setValue(setValue);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the component by a html selector and access the form inside it in the parent component. For example you can put

```
<form-component #fm> </form-component> and then you can refer <button (click) = "fm.myForm.get(key).clearValidators();"> </button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked.  However, once we fix one issue, of course another has popped up.  Is there a way to reapply all validators to the form group, if the user changes their input value?  Example, boolean input, user selects 'Yes', form validation has been cleared.  They now click 'No', form validation should be reapplied.

Comment: You can use .setValidators() methods eg fm.myForm.get(key).setValidators(this.validationType[key]);

Validation type is a defined array like validationType = {
'surname': [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[\\w\\s/-/(/)]{3,50}$')],
'initials': [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(4)]
}

Answer (score 0):

I assume your template is structured as follows

```
<parent>
   <child1></child1>   // contains boolean value, which can be used to toggle form on child2 component 
   <child2></child2> // contains form
</parent>
```

In parent.html

Pass @Output parameter to child1 component and emit it on toggle of boolean

```
<child1 (clearFormInChild2)="clearFormInChild2()"></child1>
```

Add  reference variable to child2 component as follows

```
<child2 #child2ref></child2>
```

In child1.component.ts

```
import { EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
Class child2 {
  @Output clearFormInChild2 = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onToggleOfBoolean() {
      this.clearFormInChild2.emit({//optional data});
  }
}
```

In parent.component.ts

```
Class ParentComp {
  @ViewChild('child2ref') child2ref: Child2Component;

  clearFormInChild2() {
     this.child2ref.clearForm();
  }
}
```

In child2.component.ts

```
clearForm() {
// clear form
}
```